# LaTeX3 how to use content/value of predefined command in token list/string?

Tags: expl3, expansion, latex3, strings, token-lists

First of all, I guess that will be a very easy answer for people who are experienced in `expl3`. But for me its new and I'm very willing to learn that stuff to understand Latex3 better. So I hope for some pro  help here.

What i want to achieve is the following:

First an userdefined command which has a simple sentence as content. Let's say `\NewDocumentCommand{\testcommand}{}{A Test Sentence for expl3}`

Now I want to store *the content* of the command in a token list or string. So that it can be printed/used or counted. The latter is needed, because I want to use the number of characters in an if-condition which activates different commands depending on the total count.

My MWE looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass[%
]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\NewDocumentCommand{\testcommand}{}{A Test Sentence for expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \test_tl

\tl_set:Nn \test_tl {\testcommand}

\NewDocumentCommand{\showteststring}{}{
    \tl_use:N \test_tl \par
    \tl_count:N \test_tl
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\countteststring}{}{
    \tl_to_str:N \test_tl \par
    \str_count:N \test_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    \showteststring
    
    \countteststring
    
\end{document}
```

`\showteststring` prints the content of `\testcommand` correctly using `\tl_use:N`, but `\tl_count:N` only counts one token; of course this token is `\testcommand`.

The same for the for `\countteststring`. It converts only the command-sequence `\testcommand` into a string and counts the 13 characters of the command-sequence itself.

So I need to expand `\testcommand` first. But my tries so far didn't offer any success. For instance, I tried:

`\tl_set:Nx \test_tl {\testcommand}` (with **x**) instead of `\tl_set:Nn \test_tl {\testcommand}`. It compiles fine, but the output remains the same.

I also tried some variants with `\exp_args:N`, but didn't get it to work, because I don't fully understand where to place it and which argument specifier to use in `expl3` syntax.

I also thought about the **v**/**V** argument specifier, but couldn't get it to work.

I looked into the **interface3** doc. But its overwhelming in case of informations and I couldn't figure out the right commands so far. Further, I searched Tex.SE and read the blog by [Ziyue Xiang](https://www.alanshawn.com/latex3-tutorial/#macro-expansion-control-v); also very informative, but not the specific solution I'm looking for (or, of course, I may have overlooked something).

Thus, I am already thankful in advance for any help or hint! For an explanation I would also be very grateful, so I understand it better next time!

Comment: you should follow the expl3 naming scheme, so use `\tl_new:N \l_lukeflo_test_tl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared `\testcommand` as a document command: these are protected from expansion. That means that `\tl_set:Nx \l_test_tl { \testcommand }` doesn't change the result. I would declare `\testcommand` as an expandable command and use `V`-type expansion:

```latex
\newcommand*\testcommand{A Test Sentence for expl3}
\tl_set:NV \l_test_tl \testcommand
```

etc.

Comment: thank you, that did it. I just didn't had that option in mind. In ther interfache doc it looks like that `\tl_set:(NV|Nv|No|Nf|Nx|cn|cV|cv|co|cf|cx)`, what makes it easy to overlook something.

Comment: Btw: Is there a possibility to use the `xparse` commands for it? Since, when I'm using `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\testcommand}{}{<text>}` it isn't working like expected. Only `newcommand*` does.

Comment: Expandable document commands will work, but here you are not using a document command, it's a variable containing text. (At the TeX level, the expandablity of something created by `\newcommand` and by `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` are the same.)

Comment: @lukeflo what Joseph said, but notice that a `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` doesn't work in `\tl_set:NV`, as it needs more expansion steps than a `\newcommand`-defined macro, so with it you'd have to use `\tl_set:Nx`.

Comment: @Skillmon tahnk you, that works. Understanding expansion and their steps still is my greatest concern. But it seems that it is a step by step learning by doing way to enlightment. Wish their would be an abbreviation... :D

Comment: @lukeflo remember that for a simple data-storage a `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` isn't the correct thing to do! You only need `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` in very few situations where you need the extra power for your argument processing and the expandability.

Comment: For the simple case I asked for this solution works just fine and has the least characters to type, so it's the accepted answer. Nevertheless, egreg's approach is also very interesting and offers many additional use cases. Therefore, I will also use it in my template. Thanks to all contributors!!!

Answer (score 5):

The `\NewDocumentCommand` facility is aimed at offering more powerful argument parsing than the legacy `\newcommand`. It is not at all suitable for defining “text containers”.

If you want text containers, define an infrastructure for them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definecontainer}{mm}
 {
  \tl_clear_new:c { g_lukeflo_cont_#1_tl }
  \tl_gset:cn { g_lukeflo_cont_#1_tl } { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usecontainer}{m}
 {
  \tl_use:c { g_lukeflo_cont_#1_tl }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\countcontainer}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {% count as string
    \str_count:e { \tl_to_str:v { g_lukeflo_cont_#2_tl } }
   }
   {% count as tl
    \tl_count:c { g_lukeflo_cont_#2_tl }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definecontainer{test}{A Test Sentence for expl3}
\definecontainer{test2}{abc}

\begin{document}

`\usecontainer{test}' has \countcontainer{test} items

`\usecontainer{test}' has \countcontainer*{test} tokens

`\usecontainer{test2}' has \countcontainer{test2} items

`\usecontainer{test2}' has \countcontainer*{test2} tokens

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\tl_count:N` will not count spaces, whereas they're counted when the token list is first converted into a string.

Comment: Hi @egreg, your approach looks very interesting and also adaptable. But if I try to compile it, I get an *undefined control sequence* error for the lines containing the starred version `\countcontainer*`

Comment: @lukeflo What control sequence turns out to be undefined? Possibly it is `\str_count:e`. Ensure first to have an up-to-date TeX distribution.

Comment: Have to check it tomorrow or Sunday, when I'm back at home. But my Distro ist TexLive 2022 and therefore relatively up-to-date.

Comment: @lukeflo “relatively” ;-) Anyway, you may try to add `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_count:n { e }` just before `\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Comment: @greg. A blasting fast answer, thanks ;) I'll try it out. Notwithstanding, an update to TL 2023 is already planned. I will check afterwards, if that was the reason.

Comment: unfortunately, the `cs_generate_variant` didn't help. The `! Undefined control sequence` message says `<argument> \tl_to_str:v {g_lukeflo_cont_test_tl}`.

Comment: @lukeflo: `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_to_str:N {v}`

Comment: The last `cs_generate` also didn't work. I tested all variants again. `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_count:n { e }` also still ends in an `Undefined control sequence` error, as mentioned above, but the PDF output is correct. So maybe its really the outdated TexLive version...

Comment: @lukeflo If you don't tell ***what*** control sequence turns out to be undefined it's just guesswork.

Comment: Yes, I'm still writing the second comment containing the error message. Seems to be to long for one comment. `cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_to_str:N {v}` throws the following error: `Variant form 'v' deprecated for base form '\tl_to_str:N'. One (LaTeX3)        should not change an argument from type 'N' to type 'v': (LaTeX3) base form only accepts a single token argument.` and `l.16 cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_to_str:N { v }
LaTeX does not know anything more about this error, sorry.`

Comment: I have to delay further testing until tomorrow. So please relax and enjoy the last parts of Sunday night (in case, that you also live in an European time zone), no need to hurry; and of course, thank you again ;)

Comment: @lukeflo Sorry, it should be `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_to_str:n { v }`

Comment: At work, my laptop at the office already has TexLive 2023 installed, tried it right now, and it works fine without any additional command. So, this might be the obstacle of my test file at home. I'll of course test your last approach, just for the sake of completness, but then update my private TL distro ASAP ;)

Comment: Just to complete it: I updated TL on my private notebook. Now your code works perfect without any `cs_generate_variant`!